# Is it possible to replace content from multiple foreign keys when doing a query?

Tags: sql, database, denormalization

I have the following tables:

```
TABLE PLAYER
id | name
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D

TABLE PAIRINGS
id | player_a | player_b
1  | 3        |1
2  | 2        |4
```

Both columns in table Pairings are foreign keys to column id of table player.

My problem is, I would like to avoid making a query from code every time I want to know which is my player's name (like, `Select name From Player Where Id = pairings.player_a`). I have thought about adding *Name* as an extra columnd to Pairings table, but that would denormalize it.

Instead, it would be nice if I could get the names in just one query, like:

```
RESULT
player_a | player_b
C        | A
B        | D
```

Is it this possible? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join the `PAIRINGS` table to the `PLAYER` table, twice:

```
SELECT
    p1.name AS player_a,
    p2.name AS player_b
FROM PAIRINGS pr
INNER JOIN PLAYER p1
    ON pr.player_a = p1.id
INNER JOIN PLAYER p2
    ON pr.player_b = p2.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it!  One of the points of using a relational database is that data is stored in only one place.  That is a big convenience.  Of course, there are exceptions, but these exceptions should have firm reasons.

In this case, just define a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_pairings AS
    SELECT p.*, pa.name AS player_a_name,
           pb.name AS player_b_name
    FROM PAIRINGS p JOIN
         PLAYER pa
         ON p.player_a = pa.id JOIN
         PLAYER pb
         ON p.player_b = pb.id;
```

When you query from the view, you will see the names, along with all the other information in the `PAIRINGS` table.

Answer (score 1):

Hope can help you

```
Select * Into #PLAYER From (
    Select 1 [ID], 'A' [Name] Union All
    Select 2 [ID], 'B' [Name] Union All
    Select 3 [ID], 'C' [Name] Union All
    Select 4 [ID], 'D' [Name] 
) A

Select * Into #PAIRINGS From (
    Select 1 [ID], 3 [PLAYER_A], 1 [PLAYER_B] Union All
    Select 2 [ID], 2 [PLAYER_A], 4 [PLAYER_B]
) A

Select 
    P.ID, A.NAME, B.NAME 
From #PAIRINGS P
Left Join #PLAYER A On A.ID = P.PLAYER_A
Left Join #PLAYER B On B.ID = P.PLAYER_B
```

You can create view, for avoid making query
Example

```
Create View vwPAIRINGS As
    Select 
        P.ID, A.NAME, B.NAME 
    From #PAIRINGS P
    Left Join #PLAYER A On A.ID = P.PLAYER_A
    Left Join #PLAYER B On B.ID = P.PLAYER_B
```

After that, just select usual 
**Select * from vwPAIRINGS**